# PC beeping after replacing RAM and then placing original RAM back into it

Tags: memory, ddr3

It's a desktop PC. It beeps 3 times fast, continuously until it reboots. The BIOS is not loaded, by the way. No screen appears. I already changed back to the previous RAM card and it still keeps beeping.

It started immediately after I replaced the 2GB ram DDR3 for an old 4GB DDR3. I might have installed it wrong, since when I removed the old 2GB card it jumped, but after I replaced it for the 4GB, if I remove the 4GB card, it won't jump.

Both are 1.5v, no low voltage. One is green, the other is blue.

Answer (score 2):

The internal PC speaker (the thing you hear directly from the motherboard, without going through the operating system) beeps to tell you that there has been a process with the boot process if the problem has occurred before it has been possible to show anything on screen. In general, just Google something like "speaker beep meaning." I did and I got there: https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/beep-codes

It produced this list:

- 1 Beep - Refresh Failure: Reseat/replace memory, troubleshoot motherboard.
- 2 Beeps - Parity Error: Reseat/replace memory, troubleshoot motherboard.
- **3 Beeps - Memory Error (first 64KB): Reseat/replace memory.**
- 4 Beeps - Timer Failure: Troubleshoot motherboard.
- 5 Beeps - Processor Failure: Troubleshoot CPU, motherboard.
- 6 Beeps - Keyboard Controller Failure: Troubleshoot keyboard, motherboard.
- 7 Beeps - Virtual Mode Exception Error: Troubleshoot CPU, motherboard.
- 8 Beeps - Display Memory Failure: Troubleshoot graphics card, motherboard.
- 9 Beeps - ROM BIOS Checksum Failure: Replace ROM BIOS, troubleshoot motherboard.
- 10 Beeps - CMOS Shutdown Register Failure: Troubleshoot motherboard.

These codes may  vary a bit, but the first ones are generally always the same.

As this list confirms, there might have been a problem when you changed your memory DIMMs. There are two possible problems:

- Either your memory DIMMs are damaged. Bad news. Or
- No big problem! You just didn't insert the DIMMs correctly! This happens very often when people are not used to inserting memory. Just insert it again. Make sure that the part that keeps in it place pops back in and keeps it secured in.

Also make sure that your motherboard and CPU can actually handle the type of memory you're trying to install. Some CPUs or motherboards will not handle memory DIMMs over a certain capacity or speed, for example.

Also keep in mind that if you do not fill all of the memory slots of your motherboard, you may have to place the DIMMs in specific positions. Refer to the manual of your motherboard, or try to find a PDF of the manual online.

Comment: To elaborate: To remove the DIMM you press on the clips at both ends to pop it out. To insert a DIMM you first make sure the clips are in the open position. Insert the DIMM to make sure the notch in the middle aligns with the slot (it only fits one way) and press it down firmly. The clips at either end should come back in the closed position (vertical) by themselves. If not the DIMM isn't inserted fully. Pushing the DIMM in takes usually a bit more force than people expect. A lot of first-timers don't insert the DIMM fully because they are afraid they break it.